# Working out which data point to increment PHP

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have created an array with 10 timestamps each 1 day apart:

```
$data_points = array();
$now = time();
$one_day = 60 * 60 * 24;

for($i = 1; $i <= 10; ++$i) {
  $key = $now - ($one_day * $i);
  $data_points[$key] = 0;
}

print_r($data_points);

Array
(
    [1328642414] => 0
    [1328556014] => 0
    [1328469614] => 0
    [1328383214] => 0
    [1328296814] => 0
    [1328210414] => 0
    [1328124014] => 0
    [1328037614] => 0
    [1327951214] => 0
    [1327864814] => 0
)
```

Now I have a array of tasks that have started at various times in the last 10 days, I want to see which day my task fell into.

I was going to loop through each `$data_point` and see if the start time is greater than the current day and less than the next, then increment that data point

is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Instead of using timestamps in your array you could use "yyyy-mm-dd" and then use DateTimes instead of timestamps and increment respective days using DateTime->format().

Comment: What does your tasks array look like?

Comment: If you don't have DateTime, you can use `date` to get a "Y-m-d" formatted representation of a timestamp. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: I should have been more clear, the data_points are 1 day apart but they wont wont be from 00:00 to 23:59 they could be from 08:56 to 08:55

Answer (score 1):

Well, to reduce your search time you could put your data into a binary search tree rather than a simple array.

Whether or not that's worth the trouble depends on how big your data set is.  Of course, you'd also have to re-balance your tree every so often as you add new dates.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

```
$now = new DateTime();
$task = new DateTime('2012-02-20');
$interval = $taks->diff($now);
echo 'Here is the position you need:' . $interval->format('%R%a days');
```

** Updated to avoid use of DateTime as asked in comment **

```
$now = date('Ymd');
$task = date('Ymd',$tasktime);
$interval = $task - $now;
```

The interval is the number you expect.

Comment: Unfortunately the DateTime Class ins't available in my environment

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a better method.

Assuming you have task starting timestamps in an array, the algorithm will be something like :

```
for each task starting timestamp
    timestamp <- $now - timestamp // you will obtain task age in seconds
    timestamp <- timestamp / (60*60*24) // you will obtain task age in days
    // round resulting timestamp with a precision of 0 if you want to obtain the task age in integer days.
end for each
```

In this way you will loop on only one array. This will be less expensive than your method.

Obviously, if your tasks come from a SQL database, there will be a greater solution in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but since there are no accepted answers, and it seems like a fun question to answer - here we go!

Based on your question, your algorithm has the [Big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) of `O(10n)` where `n` is the number of tasks.  This means, that it is fairly efficient compared to a lot of things.  As pointed out, a binary search tree would be faster having `O(log(n))`, however implementing it wouldn't really be worth the saved time during processing.  Though, you can make it slightly more efficient and have a resulting `O(n)` by using something like:

```
$now = time();
$oneDay = 86400; //60 * 60 * 24
foreach($tasks as $task) {
    //assuming now that $task is the timestamp of the task
    //extra paranthesis added for easier reading
    $dif = $now - ($oneDay * ceil(($now - $task) / $oneDay));
    $data_points[$dif]++;
}
```

The math in the diff is as follows.  `$now-$task` is the difference between the two timestamps in seconds, we divide by `$oneDay` to get the number of days in the past the task occurred.  Now, assuming that `$now` is the start of a new day, and if an event happened just 12 hours ago it was 'yesterday', we use `ceil` to round it to the next integer so '.5' becomes '1'.  From there, we multiply by `$oneDay` to get the number of seconds of the days that have passed - to work with the `$data_points` array that you previously created. We then take that result and subtract it from `$now`, again to work with your `$data_points` array.  That result gives us a time stamp that we can use that matches those in the array you created, and we use it as the 'key' for it and increment accordingly.

This will prevent you from having to loop through the entire `$data_points` array for each task, and thus reducing its complexity from `O(10n)` to `O(n)`.

Anyways, I hope that answer helps explain why your formula isn't that inefficient, but shows how to make it ever so slightly more efficient.